# What are the algorithms behind the Level 1 and Level 2 compression using Jlink (Java 9)?

Tags: java, compression, java-9, jlink

The documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm#JSWOR-GUID-CECAC52B-CFEE-46CB-8166-F17A8E9280E9) says:

```
Level 1 -> Constant String sharing
Level 2 -> zip
```

My questions are:

```
1). Which strings get shared ?
2). Who share these strings ?
3). Compression in Level 2 does not create a zip file. Then how it is a zip compression ?
```

Comment: 1) In the best case, *all of them*. 2) All classes within the image. 3) You don’t need a “zip file” to do “zip compression”, which is a colloquial term for the [`DEFLATE` compression algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) that has been used by different container formats.

Comment: @Holger That looks like an answer, why not make it one?